# Using BMCT to prove the sequence $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + a_n}$ is bounded and increasing.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

## My solution:

Proof of (1)

$$< \sqrt{2 + 2} \text{ by I. H.}$$

$$= 2$$ As required. Therefore by PMI $\{a_n\}$ is bounded above by 2

Proof of (2)

$$(a_n - 2)(a_n + 1) < 0$$

Therefore $\{a_n \}$ is strictly increasing.

By BMCT it states that if a sequence is bounded above and strictly increasing, then it converges. Therefore this sequence by BMCT converges.

Is this correct? Is there anything else I should say or add?

Comment: It's correct, I think

Comment: It's correct.. just mention that all terms are positive..

Comment: I think your proof is fine, but, my gob, you love your acronymns!  I had to read it three times to figute out what BMCT, WTS, PMI, or IH meant. (I never did figure out what BCMT was...)

Comment: BMCT is what I said xd, Its bounded monotonic comparison theorem. (I just copy my prof she loves using acronyms, she even uses acronym for function by putting fcn)

Comment: Would be appreciated to explain WTS, PMI, or IH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the following reasoning.
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\sqrt{2+a_n}-a_n=\frac{2+a_n-a_n^2}{\sqrt{2+a_n}+a_n}=\frac{(2-a_n)(a_n+1)}{\sqrt{2+a_n}+a_n}$$
and after your proof of $a_n<2$ we get that $\{a_n\}$ is increasing.

Comment: Thanks for showing another way to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generalization.
My original answer is at the end.

If
$a_{n+1}
=\sqrt{a_n+d^2-d}
$
where $d > 1$,
then once
$a_n < d$
then
$a_n \to d$
linearly.

This problem is the case
$d = 2$.

If $a_n \lt d$
then
$a_{n+1} \lt \sqrt{d+d^2-d}
=d
$,
so that
all subsequent $a_n < d$.

Let $a_n = b_n+d$.
Want to show that
$b_n \to 0$.

Since
$0 < a_n < d$,
$-d < b_n < 0$
or
$d^2-d < b_n+d^2 < d^2$
or
$\sqrt{d^2-d} < \sqrt{b_n+d^2} < d
$.

Then
$b_{n+1}+d
=\sqrt{b_n+d+d^2-d}
=\sqrt{b_n+d^2}
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
b_{n+1}
&=\sqrt{b_n+d^2}-d\\
&=(\sqrt{b_n+d^2}-d)\dfrac{\sqrt{b_n+d^2}+d}{\sqrt{b_n+d^2}+d}\\
&=\dfrac{b_n}{\sqrt{b_n+d^2}+d}\\
\text{so}\\
|b_{n+1}|
&=\dfrac{|b_n|}{|\sqrt{b_n+d^2}+d|}\\
&\lt\dfrac{|b_n|}{\sqrt{d^2-d}+d}\\
\end{array}
$

so $b_n \to 0$
linearly.

Note that
this also shows that
$|b_{n+1}|
\gt \dfrac{|b_n|}{2d}
$,
so the convergence
is at most linear.

Since $b_n \to 0$,
$\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}
\to \dfrac1{2d}
$,
so this is the
exact rate of convergence.

---

If $a_n \lt 2$
then
$a_{n+1} \lt \sqrt{4}
= 2$,
so the sequence is bounded.

Let $a_n = b_n+2$.
Want to show that
$b_n \to 0$.

Since
$0 < a_n < 2$,
$-2 < b_n < 0$
or
$2 < b_n+4 < 4$
or
$\sqrt{2} < \sqrt{b_n+4} < 2$.

$b_{n+1}+2
=\sqrt{b_n+4}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
b_{n+1}
&=\sqrt{b_n+4}-2\\
&=(\sqrt{b_n+4}-2)\dfrac{\sqrt{b_n+4}+2}{\sqrt{b_n+4}+2}\\
&=\dfrac{b_n}{\sqrt{b_n+4}+2}\\
\text{so}\\
|b_{n+1}|
&=\dfrac{|b_n|}{|\sqrt{b_n+4}+2|}\\
&\lt\dfrac{|b_n|}{2+\sqrt{2}}\\
\end{array}
$

so $b_n \to 0$
linearly.

Note that
this also shows that
$|b_{n+1}|
\gt \dfrac{|b_n|}{4}
$,
so the convergence
is at most linear.

Since $b_n \to 0$,
$\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}
\to \dfrac14
$.

Comment: How it comes to "Let $a_n = b_n+d$. Want to show that
$b_n \to 0$. Since $0 < a_n < d$"? I mean with $a_n = b_n+d$ and $0 < a_n < d$ Isn't it direct to say $b_n\to0$?